# Print string shows symbols

Tags: c, arrays, string, itoa

I'm trying to write an ITOA (integer to array) function using pointers.

So this is what I got so far. I debugged and it works just fine. The thing is, the printing itself doesn't work. I'm adding two screenshots.

Would appreciate some help.

```
int num_length(int number)
{
    int count = 0;

    while (number > 0)
    {
        count++;
        number /= 10;
    }

    return count;
}

void itoa(int number, char *strptr)
{
    int number_len = num_length(number);
    char *start = strptr;
    strptr += number_len - 1;

    while (strptr >= start)
    {
        *strptr = number % 10;
        number /= 10;
        strptr--;
    }
}

void print_string(char *strptr)
{
    while (*strptr != '\0')
    {
        printf("%c", *strptr);
        strptr++;
    }
}

void main(void)
{
    int number;
    char number_in_string[N] = { '\0' };
    char *strptr = &(number_in_string[0]);
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &number);

    itoa(number, strptr);

    print_string(number_in_string);
    getch();
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: don't spam tags - this isn't c++.

Comment: `*strptr = number % 10;` -> `*strptr = (number % 10) + '0';`

Comment: print_string:  printf ("%s", my_null_terminated_str)  just a thought.

Comment: @Maya ‘*I debugged and it works just fine.*’ OK, so what's wrong then?

Comment: [`int main(void)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get an array of numeric *characters* (as seems evident by your `print_string`<sup>(a)</sup> function), you'll need to adjust the values appropriately:

```
*strptr = number % 10 + '0';
```

As per your debugging output (`'\x2'`, `'\x5'`, `'\x5'`) , you're correctly getting the individual digits of the number but those are *binary* values, not the character representations.

Turning the former into the latter involves adding `'0'` (0x30 if you're using ASCII, for example). C guarantees that the numeric values are contiguous so this is safe.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> ... which could, by the way, be replaced with a simple:

```
printf("%s", number_in_string);
```

in your `main` function.